# Internet Explorer, ainda devo me preocupar com ele?

Tags: internet-explorer, webdesign

Hoje ao desenvolver um novo *site*, devo ainda me preocupar com compatibilidade com versões antigas do ***Internet Explorer***, ou já superamos esta fase?

Pergunto isso pois hoje recebi a homologação de um usuário de um site que desenvolvemos usando [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) e [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)(estou usando a versão 1.10 e não a 2.0), e na homologação ele reclamou que o site fica extremamente lento e com o layout "bagunçado" no [ie7](/questions/tagged/ie7). E disse que ele não teria como atualizar para [ie8](/questions/tagged/ie8).

Então, ainda faz sentido desenvolver pensando em versões antigas do IE?

Navegadores de web mais usados no Brasil e no Mundo em janeiro - http://blog.locaweb.com.br/geral/navegadores-de-web-mais-usados-no-brasil-e-no-mundo-em-janeiro/

O IE é de 2006 e ainda tem gente usando! - http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer

Comment: Sim, infelizmente ainda temos que ficar preocupados com o IE

Comment: Nas empresas de ***desenvolvimento*** para o setor financeiro que conheço, todas usam IE como navegador padrão. Isso porque as estações dos clientes todas tem IE. Num banco internacional muito grande para o qual prestei serviços, as era IE 7!

Comment: Gostaria de saber o motivo de não atualizarem.

Comment: "[...] e na homologação ele reclamou que o site fica extremamente lento e com o layout "bagunçado" no Internet Explorer 7." Isso por si só não responde sua pergunta? Se o cliente pagou para rodar no IE7 e você aceitou, seu site deve funcionar no IE7, não?

Comment: Complementando, usuário de `Windows XP` podem atualizar até o `Internet Explorer 8`. Esse sistema ainda tem relativamente grande marketshare porém seu suporte acaba agora em abril de 2014. No `Vista` pode-se atualizar até o `Internet Explorer 9` porém acredito que seu marketshare já seja menor do que do `Windows 8`. `Windows 7` ou superior rodam até `Internet Explorer 11`, mais novo até então.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A resposta não é sim ou não porque essa não é a pergunta certa. Ela envolve **questões técnicas** e questões de **levantamento de requisitos**.

Cito abaixo três principais tópicos que devem ser levados em conta ao tomar essa decisão. Elas são baseadas em anos de experiência, tanto como desenvolvedor web como com contato com clientes. Atentem ao fato que essa decisão começa antes mesmo do projeto iniciar e antes do preço ser definido.

### Publico alvo

Faça análise do publico alvo para tentar ver algum padrão antes de contra-argumentar seu cliente. Se não há um nixo específico, você poderá assumir que a média encontrada em sites da internet será a média do seu cliente. Porém, se há um nixo específico, por exemplo seu cliente ter um site com produtos para empresas que tendem ter computadores antigos, você naturalmente terá que levar a sério a questão de suporte a navegadores mais antigos.

Tipos de aplicações publico alvos que são bem diferentes da média, e tendem a forçar suporte a navegadores antigos

- Bancos
- Sites para governo
- Sites de comercio eletrônico (porte grande)
- Sites de notícias com foco em regiões não metropolitanas
- Intranets (cujo público interno use navegadores antigos)

> Público alvo é a métrica mais importante para definir qual versão de navegadores deverá suportar. Seja solidário com o contratante e não faça ele perder clientes, e, se necessário, cobre a mais já considerando isso.

### Funcionalidades do site

Caso o cliente tenha solicitado um site responsivo, ou com funcionalidades que somente navegadores recentes lidam bem, use isso como argumento favorável para remover suporte a navegadores antigos. Considere fortemente isso no preço caso o site não seja básico.

> Ao usar bibliotecas de terceiro, sempre olhe o suporte delas a navegadores antigos antes de usá-las. Você jamais deverá prometer suporte a um navegador mais antigo do que uma biblioteca que usa explicitamente diz suportar.

### Preço

Dar suporte a navegadores antigos implica em preço. Argumente com seu cliente e o deixe ciente **antes de fechar o acordo** que custará mais caro suporte a um navegador ancião, a exemplo de IE6 e IE7 na data desta resposta. O argumento preço em geral fará ele desistir ou pagar mais caro pelo serviço.

> Preço é uma variável que o cliente poderá alterar se ele realmente fizer questão da versão de navegador. Tenha isso em mente.

### Decisão final

Por fim, tome em consideração o **publico alvo**, **funcionalidades do site** e **preço do projeto** com seu cliente. O ideal é sempre pedir navegadores mais recentes possível, porém fortemente recomendo a não forçar algo que, por questão técnica, seria necessário, como é o caso do publico alvo do cliente: não há como obrigar o cliente a usar outro navegador, e isso pode impactar em vendas. Todos os outros pontos, como funcionalidades e preços, são discutíveis.

> Mesmo que seu site não tenha sido projetado para funcionar em uma versão mais antiga, se não for difícil, implemente bibliotecas que só são carregadas em versões antigas do IE para dar suporte a elas.

---

### Exemplo prático

Em geral, **o cliente não estará disposto a pagar e nem é interessante do ponto de vista técnico e de público alvo dar suporte a navegadores que tem 1% ou menos de usuários que irão usar seu site.** Na data desta resposta, isso significa que IE8 ainda deverá ter suporte.

### Conversa prévia e contrato com cliente

- Defina por escrito e assinado entre as partes o suporte a navegadores antes do projeto iniciar. Isso evita problemas
- A não ser que o cliente reclame, deixe em contrato que o site deverá ser funcional em todos os navegadores homologados, porém pequenas diferenças visuais poderão ocorrer devido ao suporte muito amplo de navegadores, porém tais diferenças jamais deverão atrapalhar a funcionalidade do site
- Informalmente, ou formalmente no contrato, diga que o site poderá funcionar em outros navegadores, inclusive os mais antigos, porém esse suporte não é garantido
- Informalmente, ou formalmente no contrato, diga que para dar suporte a navegadores mais antigos, a contratada poderá adicionar bibliotecas javascript que melhora essa compatibilidade, porém não tem como se comprometer que realmente funcionará em todos os casos, e explicitamente diga que um navegador mais antigo tenderá a executar seu site mais devagar que um navegador mais moderno, independente da máquina que o executa.

Comment: Eu tiraria só a parte da opinião, ou mesclaria ela com o resto da resposta, só pra evitar comentários da moderação.

Comment: Vou alterar o texto de modo que fique mais coerente

Answer (score 6):

Sim e não.

Isso depende mesmo é do escopo do projeto, se seu cliente exige que funcione no [ie8](/questions/tagged/ie8) ou superior SIM, você vai ter que se preocupar em deixar o site completamente compatível com o mesmo.

Se o cliente não fizer restrições no momento da contratação do serviço ou simplesmente disser que deve ser *crossbrowser*, não se preocupe com as versões que não mais recebem suporte de seus produtores, tanto [ie](/questions/tagged/ie) quanto os outros *browsers*.

Hoje as versões do [ie](/questions/tagged/ie)que ainda recebem suporte da [microsoft](/questions/tagged/microsoft) são [ie8](/questions/tagged/ie8)[ie9](/questions/tagged/ie9)[ie10](/questions/tagged/ie10)e[ie11](/questions/tagged/ie11), qualquer versão anterior a essas irão possuir extensos problemas de compatibilidade e de segurança e devem ser atualizados.

Não recomendo o uso de bibliotecas para aumentar a compatibilidade do *site*, isso normalmente deixa o *site* mais lento do que deveria ser.

Comment: Um cliente não dizer explicitamente que quer suporte ao IE < 8 não significa que não queira. Na dúvida, é sempre preferível perguntar para deixar claro.

Comment: Um cliente não especificar bem o seu projeto resulta em mudanças no escopo, o que acarreta em re-trabalho e consequentemente em aumento do valor final do produto. A etapa de planejamento deve ser a que mais demanda tempo, para queando se chegar na etapa de produção se evitar o re-trabalho e conseguir se manter minimamente a espectativa com relação ao projeto.

Comment: Mas não é isso que a resposta diz. A resposta diz "se não diz nada, faça o que quer". Isso não impede mudanças de escopo. Isso *causa* mudanças de escopo.

Comment: Não é "se não diz nada, faça o que quer", é "se não diz nada, faça para os mais compatíveis" ou "se não diz nada, faça para os que são *defalt*".

Comment: Mas diferentes clientes assumem diferentes versões como "default". Na dúvida, deve-se sempre clarificar.

Comment: O *default* seria se você ou a empresa em que você trabalha já tem um política definida pra isso. Eu tenho uma política pessoal chamada `byeIE`, não me importo nem um pouco com o IE se não estiver definido e especificado desde o início e se o cliente quiser depois ele vai ter que pagar a mais por isso ou fecha contrato com outra pessoa.

Comment: Uma política de empresa definida é um tipo (perfeitamente válido) de indicação explicita. O importante é que o "cliente" conheça essa política.

Comment: E é essa a ideia. O cliente não disse nada? Faça da forma mais rápida e fácil, não tente adivinhar o que passa na cabeça do cliente, isso normalmente da merda.

Comment: adivinhar != perguntar-lhe

Comment: E eu pergunto na definição do escopo, se nesse momento ele não define isso...

Answer (score 3):

Não.

Fizeram uma biblioteca em JavaScript que corrige os problemas de padrões das versões antigas do Internet Explorer, acessível através do link abaixo:

https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Não apenas isso, os compiladores de CSS ainda geram código para o IE:

- SASS: http://sass-lang.com/
- LESS: http://lesscss.org/
- Stylus: http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/

Comment: Legal vou testar essa biblioteca.

Answer (score 3):

Sim! Mas depende da versão.

Veja este gráfico que eu montei no StatCounter (Utilização por versão no último ano):

http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-BR-monthly-201301-201401

Você pode deixar de lado o IE9- e focar no IE10+

Ótima notícia pois o IE realmente vem melhorando (a apenas alguns anos nunca me imaginaria dizendo isso).

Os IE10 e IE11 estão bem melhores, inclusive com boas ferramentas de desenvolvimento.

Aqui na empresa quando algun GP vem com requisito para IE9- eu já mostro esse gráfico e tiramos fora do escopo.

Sempre vão haver problemas de portabilidade entre navegadores, mesmo o FF e o Chrome tem seus problemas mas felizmente tenho usado muito menos condicionais para diferentes navegadores nos últimos anos.

Comment: O [tag:ie10] e o [tag:ie11] realmente são surpreendentes do ponto de vista do desenvolvedor, particularmente até o [tag:ie9] vem atendendo bem apresentando os mesmos resultados que Chrome, Opera e FF em suas últimas versões, mas acredito que descartar totalmente os anteriores ainda é inviável, ainda mais se for requisito do usuário e aceito pelo desenvolvedor como é esse caso.

Answer (score 3):

Como o Erlon Charles respondeu, vai sempre depender, primeiro, de pormenores contratuais desenvolvidos com o(s) cliente(s).

Em casos em que tal não se aplica, eu costumo ir mais longe do que o colega disse e apenas dou total compatibilidade com duas versões de cada browser (a mais actual e a imediatamente anterior). Isto porque se nós, que desenvolvemos a aplicações mais recentes, não "forçarmos" que os utilizadores actualizem os seus navegadores (ou outras dependências), então irá demorar muito mais tempo para novas tecnologias se tornem padrão na Internet.

Comment: Verdade, até porque novas bibliotecas já se restringem a não suportar browsers antigos para que o desempenho seja melhor. O que eu quis dizer com biblioteca externa foi usar alguma biblioteca para forçar browser antigos a entender [tag:css3] por exemplo, eles praticamente só servem pra deixar o *site* lento e complicar a manutenibilidade